# Is there a way to create a variable from a string/variable in Perl while use strict on?

Tags: perl, variables

I have a selection of statements like so:

```
my $name = $criteria->{'name'} if $criteria->{'name'};
my $age  = $criteria->{'age'}  if $criteria->{'age'};
my $dob  = $criteria->{'dob'}  if $criteria->{'dob'};
.
.
.
# there are around 8 of these
```

And I would like to do something similar to:

```
foreach (qw/name age dob .../) {
    ${$_} = $criteria->{$_} if $criteria->{$_};
}
```

I'm sure I've done this before, but when I tried it using `use strict` it threw an error.

Is there a way to do this? Or is there a better way to do what I want? I'm just being lazy really, but if there is a way to do it, it would be interesting to see.

If it is possible to do, would it be more efficient to run memory-wise? I'm trying to improve the speed of my script.

Comment: actually, I've just realised that I wouldn't be able to initialise the variables with `my`. Maybe there still is a way?

Comment: If you want to go around `strict`, you can always `no strict vars;`, which applies only to the end of the current `{}` block.

Comment: As a way to shorten your code, you probably don't need the ifs.

Comment: as a way to *fix* the code; `my ... if ...` probably doesn't do what you want.

Comment: I've found a way to eradicate it totally; it essentially did what I wanted but I didn't actually need it; like hobbs said, I'm now just using the hash I have. Silly mistake, I think I need a holiday!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The better way is to use the hash you already have, instead of using the current package namespace as a hash. And no, you're not saving memory or time with what you're trying to do. In fact you're using more of both.

Comment: Actually, that should have been pretty obvious to me - I've spent too many months staring at this code! Thanks :)